# How to structure the contents of this view so that it is intuitive?

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation, user-expectation

I have a circle tab implemented which looks like this.

[image]

By default, it lists the circles that I'm a member of. When I search, it lists all public/private circles matching the search pattern. Removing all characters from the search box and searching lists all public/private circles (i.e empty search).

What is the best way to restructre the page such that there is an option to search either in my circles or all public/private circles? There also needs to be an intuitive way for users to list ALL circles they are a part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching between all circles and your circles is actually filtering results, so display the filters:

[image: Tabs as filters]